# rails console won't start (ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm getting 'Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.1. Please install RubyGems and try again:  http://rubygems.rubyforge.org' error. However...

```
gem -v
```

Returns "1.3.7".  afaict, I have RubyGems 1.3.7 installed...

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have multiple RubyGem versions installed, you need to export the `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME` variables

```
export GEM_PATH="/wherever/"
export GEM_HOME="/wherever/"
```

[Here's a post about it](http://formatinternet.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/multiple-rubygems-versions-gem_home-and-gem_path/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it in a day or so and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have more than one Ruby install on the system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check it in a day or so and let you know how it goes.